# In ArcGIS, I discovered the sw.lock files? What are they?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

In ArcGIS, sometimes I get a sw.lock lock file with the name of my shapefile. Example : Polygon_shape.shp.sw.lock

I know about the  .lock files (sr, ed, rd, wr) but I have never seen "sw" in the past. I'd like to know where it came from since I get it using my ArcObjects application and it is intermittent.